# Compatibility of data size while using malloc()

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I recently studied about  **malloc()** in C with declaration as follows:

```
void *malloc(size_t size)
```

where `size_t` is unsigned int and `size` defines the no. of bytes to be reserved. 
Question is that on my system *float* values occupy 4bytes of memory. So if i make memory pointer(of float type) using malloc of 2bytes,

```
float *p;  
p = (float *)malloc(2);
```

then how come it does not give any error? Because what i think is that float data required 4 bytes so if i issue only 2 bytes to it then it may lead to some data loss.

or is it that i m understanding malloc() incorrrectly?

Comment: `size_t` is not necessarily `unsigned int`. Do not rely on it. E.g. on systems with 16 bit `int`, but 32 pointers, it is likely `unsigned long`. On x64 it is likely either `unsigned long long` (Windows, LLP64) or `unsigned long` (POSIX64, LP64).

Comment: You actually answered your question already. Read again and see where you think wrong. Remember C does not hinder you (much) to shoot your foot.

Comment: i m more concerned for second half of question

Comment: When would you expect an error?

Comment: @Olaf i don't get it. I've tried this with float values but there is no loss of data

Comment: So you expect the compiler to see the connection between the cast or the type of the pointer and the insufficient storage?

Comment: Some static analysers such as [Clang's](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html) can perhaps detect this type of bug.  At the end of the linked document is an example where `long *p = malloc(sizeof(short))` is detected, which yould help you in your case.

Comment: Think about the implications of the word **undefined**. Like in _undefined behaviour_. Remember that phrase, you will eventually encounter it a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you give, if you only allocate 2 bytes for a `float *` and then attempt to write to that location by dereferencing the pointer, you'll be writing to memory that hasn't been allocated.  This results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  That means it might work, it might core dump, or it might behave in unpredictable ways.

If you want to allocate memory for one or more floats, you would do it like this:

```
// allocates space for an array of 5 floats
// don't cast the result of malloc
int arrayLen = 5;
float *f = malloc(sizeof(float) * arrayLen);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be problematic if you try to use that pointer -actually the pointer is fine, it's the allocated memory it points to that's too small-, the reason the compiler doesn't recognize it as an error is the fact that the pointer isn't "aware" of what it points to , actually pointers are variables that contain memory addresses, so basically they're just a number, and in most cases ( as user694733 pointed out) the size of the pointer is the same whether it points to a short or a float.
what the compiler sees is a cast from (void*) to (float*) and to the compiler it's a totally valid cast.

Comment: *"the size of the pointer is the same whether it points to a short or a float"* Not necessarily. They are allowed to have different internal representations. Here the `void*` is *converted* to `float*`.

Comment: @user694733 pointers themselves are memory addresses, so they have the same size on the same machine regardless of what they point to. The explicit cast can be -and in my opinion should be- dropped.

Comment: Explicit casting should be dropped, because C does *implicit casting* when `void*` is assigned to other pointer type. Many modern systems use same presenstation for all pointers types, but it is not required by the C standard: There may still be implicit conversion.

Comment: N1570 6.2.5 p28: *"A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
pointer to a character type. 48) Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All
pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
alignment requirements as each other. **Pointers to other types need not have the same
representation or alignment requirements.**"*

Comment: I see your point, I never said that they have the same representation, i said they have the same size, i really like that you pointed that out, and i respect your tenacity

Comment: My point is that **representation includes the size too**. That is what I am trying to correct: Not all pointers are necessarily the same size!

Comment: I'm mind blown, I have been programming using c for 5 years -on different platforms- and I have never encountered a case where 2 pointers had different sizes on the same machine, but apparently the standard doesn't require it. Thank you for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering an implementation-specific result of the requirements of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **7.22.3 Memory management functions**
>
> The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to
>   the `aligned_alloc` , `calloc` , `malloc` ,  and `realloc` functions
>   is unspecified.   **The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
>   suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type
>   of object with a fundamental alignment requirement** and then used to
>   access such an object or an array of such objects in the space
>   allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

In order to provide storage "suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement", an implementation has to return memory from `malloc()` *et al* at specific offsets that are multiples of the most restrictive alignment requirement for the system.  That's usually something like 8 or 16 bytes.

Given that each and every block returned has to be aligned that way, most implementations internally create blocks of memory in multiples of the alignment requirement.

So if your system has an 8-byte alignment requirement, your `malloc()` implementation is likely to actually give you an 8-byte block of memory even though you requested two bytes.  Likewise, ask for 19 bytes and you'll likely get something like 24 in reality.

It's still undefined behavior to go beyond what you asked for, though.  And undefined behavior does unfortunately include "works just fine".

Answer (score 0):

Your question has actually nothing to do with the malloc, but rather to the data casting. In this case you have casted the bytes located starting from the address returned by malloc to float. Thus, if you later say `*p = 0.0f;` you will actually write 4 bytes to the mentioned memory area, but only 2 bytes are ligal to you to use since you have allocated only 2 bytes. Therefore, your code will compile and run with memory corruption (this either will result in crash, or in an unexpected runtime behavior later)